Dynamic import of dependencies in Angular with ESBuild
I have an application developed in Angular 17 and I have recently changed the builder for the new ESBuild compiler that Angular brings.
Everything has been fine except for importing libraries dynamically, which to my surprise, it seems that ESBuild does not support natively. As an example, this series of sentences:
export async function initialize(locale: string): Promise<void> {
    const localeMapped = CUSTOM_LOCALE_MAP[locale] || locale;

    try {
        await import(`dayjs/locale/${localeMapped}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

    dayjs.locale(localeMapped);
}

Produce the following error:

What I find strange is that in Angular if they work lazy loads of modules or components (traditionally used in the router) so, does anyone know if there is a way to solve these dynamic loads of libraries?
Thanks

The issue is the dynamic import is using a non-static string. The bundler is not able to infer which file should be bundled.
While this might have worked with Webpack and some custom comments, it was never officially supported.
See this related issue

Hello Matthieu Riegler, does this mean that if for example I set the import without a variable, it should work?

Yes, it should work if it's a static string

Correct, I have tested it and indeed it does not throw any error if the import string does not contain any variable. The question is, is there any workaround to be able to make dynamic imports through ESBuild?

I don't believe so by reading this issue https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/700#issuecomment-1954426114
